# Value Error raised when using load_datasets to download datasets from Huggingface in Python3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-datasets

When the download is completed,the error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\pythonProject\Tep.py", line 4, in <module>
    dataset = load_dataset("BAAI/COIG-PC", cache_dir=r"E:\datasets")
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\datasets\load.py", line 1809, in load_dataset
    builder_instance.download_and_prepare(
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py", line 909, in download_and_prepare
    self._download_and_prepare(
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py", line 1670, in _download_and_prepare
    super()._download_and_prepare(
  File "C:\Users\***\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\datasets\builder.py", line 993, in _download_and_prepare
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `all` is a special split keyword corresponding to the union of all splits, so cannot be used as key in ._split_generator().

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is my code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from huggingface_hub import login
login(token='****')
dataset = load_dataset("BAAI/COIG-PC", cache_dir=r"E:\datasets")
dataset.save_to_disk(r"/datasets")
```

I think the problem may occurs in renaming and spliting the data which already be downloaded.

I tried to load the dataset from .cache and have the same error